# static function in an abstract class

Tags: c++

How to implement a static function in an abstract class?? Where do I implement this?

```
class Item{
public:
  //
  // Enable (or disable) debug descriptions. When enabled, the String produced
  // by descrip() includes the minimum width and maximum weight of the Item.
  // Initially, debugging is disabled.
  static enableDebug(bool);

};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, that function needs a return type. I'll assume it's supposed to be `void`.

You implement it in a source file, just as you would implement any other method:

```
void Item::enableDebug(bool toggle)
{
  // Do whatever
}
```

There's nothing special about it being static or the `Item` class being abstract. The only difference is that you do not have access to a `this` pointer (and consequently also not to member variables) within the method.

Answer (score 1):

Static functions cannot be virtual so you implement it in the context of the class itself.  It doesn't matter if the class is abstract or not.

```
void Item::enableDebug(bool)
{    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most modern C++ compilers can (now) handle having static method implementation inside the class declaration, as in:

```
class Item {
public:

  static void enableDebug(bool value) {
      static bool isOn = false;
      isOn = value;
      std::cout << "debug is " << (isOn ? "on" : "off") << std::endl;
  }

};
```

I'm not saying this is a good idea, but does flesh out the previous answers some.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods can be implemented in any class. I just don't know if your method can be made static. Your comments suggest that the method will set some object data. In this case, your method cannot be static.